# How to pull together vectors with common components in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Sorting a list of vectors (e.g. list of lists or array of arrays with integer numbers) to make inner vectors with most amount of common integer numbers adjacent. Every component counted only once and paired only with a single number.

An example.

```
Input
[
    [ 4, 6, 2, 2, 10 ],
    [ 5, 20, 2, 7, 9 ], # 1 component is common with previous
    [ 5, 4, 2, 10, 9 ], # 3 ...
    [ 9, 6, 3, 3, 0 ], # 1 ...
    [ 5, 7, 2, 9, 5 ], # 1 ...
    [ 9, 3, 6, 7, 0 ] # 2 ...
]

Output (common match number was 1+3+1+1+2 and became 2+3+3+1+4).
[
    [ 4, 6, 2, 2, 10 ],
    [ 5, 4, 2, 10, 9 ], # 2 components are common with previous
    [ 5, 20, 2, 7, 9 ], # 3 ...
    [ 5, 7, 2, 9, 5 ], # 3 ...
    [ 9, 6, 3, 3, 0 ], # 1
    [ 9, 3, 6, 7, 0 ] # 4 ...
]
```

My current 'sorting-of-sorting' solution (Python) does not work properly:

```
def _near_vectors( vectors_ ):
    """
        Return value - changed order of indexes.
    """

    vectors = copy( vectors_ )

    # Sort each vector
    for i in range( len( vectors ) ):
        vectors[ i ] = sorted( vectors[ i ] )

    # Save info about indexes
    ind = [ ( i, vectors[ i ] ) for i in range( len( vectors ) ) ]

    sort_info = sorted( ind, key = itemgetter( 1 ) )

    return [ v[ 0 ] for v in sort_info ]
```

An example where it failes:

```
Input:
[
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 4],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 13],
    [5, 8, 9, 17],
    [5, 12, 13],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [7, 10, 11],
    [7, 11, 14, 15],
    [7, 14, 15, 16]
]

Output: the same list, that is incorrect. [5, 12, 13] must be just after [4, 5, 13].
```

It's a useful algorithm for many things, for example to pull together in time tasks with common components (components are integer indexes). May be somebody has solved the case?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you are trying to optimise.  If it is the total number of numbers shared by adjacent vectors, then the problem is as ecatmur says.  In that case, note that finding the optimal answer for some inputs will necessarily mean choosing a *locally suboptimal* pair of vectors -- intuitively, that's what makes this problem NP-hard (which in turn is what makes it impossible to solve for large instances).

Comment: @j_random_hacker I agree. There must be an additional precedency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of my current function `_near_vectors()` can by improved.

The idea: to improve a result of the simple sorting solution (which sorts partially) by a function which moves each element to more valued position (it much improves the result, moving vectors in 'vacuum' to right positions). E.g. it calculates the current value of adjacent components and checks if they can be moved to another position (with another adjacent components) with more valued links between newly formed groups.

```
def _match( v1, v2 ):
    """
        The number of identical elements in v1 and v2 where v1 and v2 are lists.
    """

    res = len(list((Counter(v1) & Counter(v2)).elements()))
    return res


def _mind( vectors, vi, i ):
    "Calculate value of position i for vector vi in vectors."
    def pos(i):
        return 0 <= i < len( vectors )

    if isinstance(vi, int):
        if pos(vi):
            v = vectors[vi][ 1 ]
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        v = vi

    if pos(i):
        return _match( vectors[ i ][ 1 ], v )
    else:
        return 0

def _near_vectors2(vectors):
    i = 0
    for v in vectors:
        max_val = 0 
        new_pos = None      
        for k in range(len(vectors)):
            if k != i:
                v = vectors[ i ][ 1 ] # current vector

                # Calc. sum of links, move if links are improved
                next_k = k + 1 if i < k else k - 1
                cur_mind = _mind(vectors, v, k) + _mind(vectors, v, next_k) - _mind(vectors, k, next_k) - _mind(vectors, v, i + 1 ) - _mind(vectors, v, i - 1 ) + _mind(vectors, i - 1, i + 1)

                if cur_mind > max_val:
                    max_val = cur_mind
                    new_pos = k     


        # move element
        if new_pos is not None:
            vectors.insert( new_pos, vectors.pop( i ) )

        i += 1

    return vectors
```

So, to make it working we can call:

```
near_indexes = _near_vectors2( near_vectors( vects ) )
```

Each element in output list consists of two components: changed index and source vector.

Remark. None of the decisions works properly without it's paired solution. Probably result is not 'absolutely' sorted, but it's vastly sorted.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) without the requirement of returning to the starting position. To avoid a negative metric, costs should be expressed as the number of elements *not* in common between adjacent lists; this gives you a triangle inequality so you can use metric TSP methods.

You *could* implement a TSP solver yourself, but it'd probably make more sense to use an existing one; for example, Google's [or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp) has Python bindings and example code for how to use them to solve TSP instances.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right, it's a method to solve the problem. However I try to find less complex decision for this local problem. Probably I 'll give a bounty for the question later.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for what it does its correct:

```
# Sort each vector
for i in range( len( vectors ) ):
    vectors[ i ] = sorted( vectors[ i ] )

# Output
[
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 4],
[4, 5, 6],
[4, 5, 13],
[5, 8, 9, 17],
[5, 12, 13],
[7, 8, 9],
[7, 10, 11],
[7, 11, 14, 15],
[7, 14, 15, 16]
]

# Save info about indexes
ind = [ ( i, vectors[ i ] ) for i in range( len( vectors ) ) ]

# Output convert to list with tuples (index,list[i])
[(0, [0, 1, 2, 3]), 
(1, [0, 1, 2, 4]), 
(2, [4, 5, 6]), 
(3, [4, 5, 13]), 
(4, [5, 8, 9, 17]), 
(5, [5, 12, 13]), 
(6, [7, 8, 9]), 
(7, [7, 10, 11]), 
(8, [7, 11, 14, 15]), 
(9, [7, 14, 15, 16])]


sort_info = sorted( ind, key = itemgetter( 1 ) )

# Output sort by list first by sorting the first elements on each list     
# then the second ones etc. For example list [4, 5, 13] comes before 
# [5, 8, 9, 17] because their first element is 4 < 5. Then 
# [5, 8, 9, 17] comes before [5, 12, 13] because the second element 
# is 8 < 12 etc.

[(0, [0, 1, 2, 3]), 
 (1, [0, 1, 2, 4]), 
 (2, [4, 5, 6]), 
 (3, [4, 5, 13]), 
 (4, [5, 8, 9, 17]), 
 (5, [5, 12, 13]), 
 (6, [7, 8, 9]), 
 (7, [7, 10, 11]), 
 (8, [7, 11, 14, 15]), 
 (9, [7, 14, 15, 16])
]
```